# What happens to checked out items when an orphaned user gets removed?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, item-level-permissions, orphan

So we are in the process of cleaning up old orphaned users who are getting sent email alerts. Is there any downside to removing these orphaned users from a site?

What happens to any files checked out/created by that user? Are there any issues when migrating to different versions of SharePoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checked out files will remain checked out to that user. Created By/Modified By will remain until you migrate that content via a content migration tool, such as Sharegate. Otherwise if you perform database attach upgrades, the data will remain consistent.